# Writing a SQL Query date range to retrieve a start date from a known end date

Tags: mysql, sql

it sounds bad from the title but it has me stumped. The scenario is I need to write a query that will get the min(start_date) from a fiscal_month_begin_date column. This dataset(query) will run in SQL Report builder and I need to build the query so when someone wants to, they can retrieve the data by choosing either: current month, 3 month, or 6 month. Being really new to building queries I am having an issue with understanding how to marry the whole thing together. Here is how the query looks right now:

```
 SELECT *
   from date_Table  
     where(
      Select fiscal_date
         from date_table
           where full_date >= TO_DATE('5/8/2015 12:00:00 AM',      'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM'));
```

So I can write a query that returns the start date, the problem is I need the date to be 6 months from today and beginning on the first day of the month and the end date is today or yesterday.

I hope you all can help.

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense and I'm struggling to understand your description of the problem. Could you provide some example data?

Comment: Is the point here to return a `start_date` based on the `end_date` being the first of this month, 3 months from now, or 6 months from now?

Comment: @CSS, yes that goal is to obtain a start date based on the end date. Say starting from today I want to go back 6 months and have the result begin with day 1 of the month.

Comment: @symcbean, sorry about that code it is a really rough look at it. If you take the top three lines out, the core of my code is starting with the second SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this declare variables and try this

```
declare @running_for datetime;
 set @running_for = getdate();

SELECT *
   from date_Table  
     where(
      Select fiscal_date 
         from date_table d
  where 
 (datepart(m,d.full_date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())))
  and 
  d.full_date <= @running_for-1   --- if it is yesterday
// d.full_date <= @running_for --- if it is today
```

Comment: thank you for the help, here is the error I get when i tried this: Error starting at line 1 in command:
procedure
Error report:
Unknown Command
Error starting at line 1 in command:
declare running_for datetime;
 set running_for = getdate();

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add '@' before variable running_for

Comment: You might want to have that month datepart as a variable as well, so the user can define this month (0), 3 months ago (3), and 6 months ago (6) or any other range as the situation becomes necessary. You can also declare and set a variable in the same line like this: `DECLARE @current_dt DATETIME = getdate(), @time_frame INT = 0;`

Comment: @HBMirza, I did have the '@' symbol before running_for, when I tried to post the code it would not let me so I removed it for posting.

Comment: I am not sure about query you wrote but this part of query should work declare running_for datetime;
 set running_for = getdate();

SELECT fiscal_date
   from date_table d
  where 
 (datepart(m,d.full_date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -6, getdate())))
  and 
 d.full_date <= running_for-1            P.S. Use '@' before running_for

Comment: @HBMirza, Well what is weird is when I copy and paste the code into the Oracle SQL developer worksheet it looks good but when I press run on the query for the DB it brings up several errors. I am using version 3.1.07 Build Main-07.42, and cannot update to latest.

Comment: I am using SQL sever 2014 Management studio where this query will work and I am not familiar with Oracle environment.

Comment: @HBMirza, sadly I am using Oracle  and not SQL....So with this little bit of information I am sure the syntax is a lot different. As i found out there isn't a GETDATE, I must use CURRENT_DATE so I need to figure out the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your computations which are not part of the database from the query. Then build up your query from simpler parts to get what you want.

Your computations include things like the start date. It has nothing to do with what's in the database, so do that computation first.

For queries, try these;

- select today's data
- select yesterday's data
- select yesterday and today
- select the current months data
- select the previous month's data
- select the previous and current month

You should be able to see your solution by working out these simpler cases.